# How do iPhones acquire date and time?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, time, ntp

Do iPhones and iPads with cellular network support [NITZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) or do they only rely on NTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Carrier.plist` file - iOS does support **NITZ**. Here' the refference on [theiphonewiki.com](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Carrier.plist).

> **Network time sync**
>
> ```
> <key>SupportsNITZ</key>
> <true/>
> ```
>
> Enables time updates through the NITZ protocol.